# Set margins for html to pdf printing in android with webView from webkit

Tags: android, printing, html2pdf

I have an Android App which renders HTML to PDF using Android (Kotlin) webView from webkit and PrintDocumentAdapter. The margins for printing are set with a @page like this:

```
@page {
    size: A4 portrait;
    margin: 20mm 15mm 20mm 15mm;
}

@media screen, print {
    html, body {
        width: 210mm;
        height: 294mm;
    }

    page {
        box-shadow: 0;
        display: block;
    }

}
```

I added with AND height due to the following reference [Chrome seems to miscalculate css sizes given in mm unit when printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22024144/chrome-seems-to-miscalculate-css-sizes-given-in-mm-unit-when-printing). But missing width ist not the problem here.
Until recent Chrome for Android Update (78.0.3904.62) the generated html did render perfectly with the desired margins to a ISO A4 pdf. When using the following PrintAttributes in Kotlin:

```
var attributes : PrintAttributes = PrintAttributes.Builder()
                .setMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A4)
                .setResolution(PrintAttributes.Resolution("pdf", "pdf", 150, 150))
                .setMinMargins(PrintAttributes.Margins.NO_MARGINS).build()
```

But after the Chrome update our app produces pdfs with 8cm margin on all four sides. I could fix the issue for now using px instead of mm. But this does not feel like the correct solution. This is the html/css which works for now:

```
@page {
    size: A4 portrait;
    margin: 22px 20px 23px 21px;
}

@media screen, print {
    html, body {
        width: 210mm;
        height: 294mm;
    }

    page {
        box-shadow: 0;
        display: block;
    }

}
```

Is this a bug in Chrome for Android or am I missing something important here?