# XSL + XML -> PDF for C#

Tags: c#, xml, pdf, xslt, nfop

I know several people asked questions like this, but no answer helped to solve my problem.

Well, I have `xsl` and `xml` and want to generate `pdf` with a processor like Apache.FOP. 
I am not able to use any `JAVA` programms like that. Just able to use C# libraries / exe.

I tried to use `nFop`:

- Version 1.x uses Java.io and..
- Version 2.0 doesn't have the ability to set XsltSettings

My current Software uses `XSL + XML -> HTML` (using standard `Stystm.Xml.Xsl` on C#) and  `wktmltopdf` to generate `PDF` from created `HTML`. 
But tables got split when they are too long for the page, and on the next page you don't have any column headers (this is very important for my problem).

I think there are no Free FO-Processor for pure C

Comment: Please stick to one language, because the solution is going to be *vastly* different depending on language (and library used)

Comment: The problem seems that your html is not designed to fit on a PDF page. `wktmltopdf` has options to change the sizing, also you could look at the options at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341485/how-to-make-a-html-page-in-a4-paper-size-pages.

Comment: It is wanted that it sometimes goes over pages.

Comment: So, you cannot use Apache FOP?

Comment: I can, I did and it worked all good. But I'm not allowed to, because java has to be installed :) I need pure C

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [FoNET](https://fonet.codeplex.com/).

```
public static bool XMLToPDF(string pXmlFile, string pXslFile, string pFoFile, string pPdfFile)
{
    string lBaseDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(pXslFile);
    XslCompiledTransform lXslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
    lXslt.Load(pXslFile);
    lXslt.Transform(pXmlFile, pFoFile);
    FileStream lFileInputStreamFo = new FileStream(pFoFile, FileMode.Open);
    FileStream lFileOutputStreamPDF = new FileStream(pPdfFile, FileMode.Create);
    FonetDriver lDriver = FonetDriver.Make();
    lDriver.BaseDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(lBaseDir);
    lDriver.CloseOnExit = true;
    lDriver.Render(lFileInputStreamFo, lFileOutputStreamPDF);
    lFileInputStreamFo.Close();
    lFileOutputStreamPDF.Close();
    return System.IO.File.Exists(pPdfFile);
}
```