# Move HTML tags onto a new page when printing

Tags: html, css

I'm writing a report based on data from a database, so the content is quite dynamic.  I wrote a bit of code that outputs a "page-break-before:always;" on every second div tag, but because of the dynamic nature of the report, some div tags spread over the page when printed.  What I want to know is, is there a way to have a div tag (or any other type of element) move down onto the new page?

An example is this:
[image: Bad paging]

See how the table starts on one page and then finishes on the second.  In an ideal world, I would place some CSS on this that would start the table on the second page

Comment: what do you mean "because of the dynamic nature of the report some div tags spread over the page"? A code example might help. have you read this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664049/can-i-force-a-page-jump-in-html-printing/1664058

Comment: I did see that @michael-coker.  Basically I'm using ASP.NET to create the report, I basically have 1 heading and then I can have multiple sections beneath that.  1 section might be 10 lines long, the next could be 30 lines.  My manager complained there was too much white space when I put the page-break-before on a header.  I tried placing it on every second one, but then some appear nicely on 1 pace, others then get part of the report / graph cut off at the bottom of one page and get rendered on the next page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML printing limit 1 page only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39206099/html-printing-limit-1-page-only)

Answer (score 0):

I would use `<table>` element to print.
This one goes nicely from page to page.
Within a table you put some div(s) / nested table(s).

This is how I do majority of my reports.