# How to add auto detect page break

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I have created a web page to show billing details. Some of the bills have lots of details and if this bill's details do not to fit into an A4 sheet of paper I want to add a page break. How can I detect that automatically, should I add a page break?

Comment: Just create a `<div>` with a width of `2480px`. The content inside should break by itself.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: [`page-break-after`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp), [`page-break-before`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pagebb.asp) and [`page-break-avoid`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pagebi.asp) *may* come in handy.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341485/how-to-make-a-html-page-in-a4-paper-size-pages) out too.

Answer (score 1):

> `page-break-before` : Specifies whether a new page should be started before
>   a particular element.
>
> `page-break-after` : Specifies how to handle page breaks after a
>   particular element.
>
> `always` : Force a page break before or after the specified element

Insert `.header`(or other name) and `.footer`(or other name) between content to website,like this:

```
<div class="header"></div>
...content...
<div class="footer"></div>

<div class="header"></div>
...content...
<div class="footer"></div>
```

after it use :

```
.header {
  page-break-before:always;
}

.footer {
  page-break-after:always;
}
```

```css
.header, .footer {
  display: none;
}

@media print {

.header, .footer {
  display: block;
}
  .header {
    page-break-before:always;
  }

  .footer {
    page-break-after:always;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
<p>...content...</p>
<div class="footer"></div>

<div class="header"></div>
<p>...content...</p>
<div class="footer"></div>
```