# Javascript Text Editor splitted by A4 pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking for an idea, how it works.

We have any rich text editor. each one has length without limit. but we want to divide as A4 dynamic pages.

My question is: how do we determine where to split each page and how to split them?

Like Google Doc.

I do not need a code. just an idea and a solution

thank you in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341485/how-to-make-a-html-page-in-a4-paper-size-pages this work for you maybe?

Comment: No, this is one time generate A4 style. We need dynamically

Comment: I don't think this is the right website for such questions.

Comment: I made a proof of concept some time ago : https://github.com/motla/vue-document-editor it's checking the page height at every user input and moves the last words to the next page if it overflows. At first it seems to work but it is not scalable if you plan to write a big document it's laggy, and it has bugs with edge cases like copy/paste etc. so I would say it's still experimental. you can check the code through, any improvement is welcome.