# Force duplicate printElement to go to the bottom part of the page using window.print();

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am planning to do a duplicated printing. The top-half is for the staff's copy, and the lower-half part is for the user's copy. We will just cut the paper in half once it's printed. How do we do this? Can the `window.print();` do this?

This is the script that I am using.

```
    function PrintAppendChangeScheduleButton() {
        printElement(document.getElementById("divID")); //Specify the DIV to be printed.

        function printElement(elem) {
            var forDOMClone = elem.cloneNode(true);
            var $forSECTIONPrint = document.getElementById("forSECTIONPrint"); //For Section Specific Print
            if (!$forSECTIONPrint) {
                var $printSection = document.createElement("div"); //For DIV Specific Print
                $forSECTIONPrint.id = "forSECTIONPrint";
                document.body.appendChild($forSECTIONPrint);
            } else {
                $forSECTIONPrint.innerHTML = "";
                $forSECTIONPrint.appendChild(forDOMClone);
                window.print();
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried duplicating `elem.cloneNode(true);`, but it does not arrange it properly.

This is what I'm working on right now.

```
    function PrintAppendChangeScheduleButton() {
        printElement(document.getElementById("divID")); //Specify the DIV to be printed.

        function printElement(elem) {
            var forDOMClone = elem.cloneNode(true);
            var forDOMCloneCUT = elem.cloneNode(true);
            var $forSECTIONPrint = document.getElementById("forSECTIONPrint"); //For Section Specific Print
            if (!$forSECTIONPrint) {
                var $printSection = document.createElement("div"); //For DIV Specific Print
                $forSECTIONPrint.id = "forSECTIONPrint";
                document.body.appendChild($forSECTIONPrint);
            } else {
                $forSECTIONPrint.innerHTML = "";
                $forSECTIONPrint.appendChild(forDOMClone);
                $forSECTIONPrint.appendChild(forDOMCloneCUT);
                window.print();
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the current printing status.

[image: current print]

This is the result that I am looking for.

Is there a way for javascript to force `$forSECTIONPrint.appendChild(forDOMCloneCUT);` to go to the lowest part of the page?

[image: duplicate print]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have hacked something together.

First, we need to know that the size of an A4 sheet is **210mm x 297mm**. I got that from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21795173/5488850).

Next, we need to convert the height (297mm) to pixels. We do that [here](https://www.unitconverters.net/typography/centimeter-to-pixel-x.htm) and get **1122.5px**.

Now we need to measure the height of the div you want to print twice, and see if **twice the height of the div is less than the size of an A4 sheet.** If yes, then we create an empty div in between the 2 clones and give it the height of whatever empty space is there  after the clones.

So here's your modified code:

```css
* {
margin: 0; 
padding: 0
}
```

```html
<div id='divID' style="border: 2px black solid; padding-bottom: 200px">
    <h1>CONTENT FROM THIS PAGE IS FROM printElement(document.getElementById('div1'))</h1>
</div>
<div id='forSECTIONPrint'></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = PrintAppendChangeScheduleButton;
        function PrintAppendChangeScheduleButton() {
            printElement(document.getElementById("divID")); //Specify the DIV to be printed.

            function printElement(elem) {
                var forDOMClone = elem.cloneNode(true);
                var forDOMCloneCUT = elem.cloneNode(true);
                var $forSECTIONPrint = document.getElementById("forSECTIONPrint"); //For Section Specific Print
                if (!$forSECTIONPrint) {
                    var $printSection = document.createElement("div"); //For DIV Specific Print
                    $forSECTIONPrint.id = "forSECTIONPrint";
                    document.body.appendChild($forSECTIONPrint);
                } else {
                    $forSECTIONPrint.innerHTML = "";
                    var elemHeight = elem.offsetHeight;
                    elem.style.display = 'none';
                    var emptySpace = document.createElement('div');
                    $forSECTIONPrint.appendChild(forDOMClone);
                    $forSECTIONPrint.appendChild(emptySpace);
                    //if there's any empty space at the bottom of the page, then set the height of the
                    //empty div in between the clones with that space height
                    if (1122.5 - (elemHeight * 2) > 0){
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            emptySpace.style.height = 1122.5 - (elemHeight * 2) + 'px';
                            window.print();
                        },100);
                    }
                    //if there's no empty space, just print right away
                    else {
                        window.print();
                    }
                    $forSECTIONPrint.appendChild(forDOMCloneCUT);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Ma'am, you just made my day. Thank you very much! this does it! I now just need to understand the changes you've made and do some tweaks.