# A4 size print-out from asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, printing

I am working on a task in which I need to arrage certain data in a particular format on asp.net web page. The asp.net page looks more like a plain report page. Then I need to allow user to take a print out of the same page in standard A4 format. If the data to be displayed on the page is more, the page is also supposed to handle page-breaks and display the page data on two (or more as required) A4 pages.

Is it possible to make a web page conform to A4 size print outs?

If yes, is it an advisable way to do so?

How can I make a web page conform to A4 size print outs?

Let me know if you need any other information on my task.

Thanks

Comment: http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/728/printer-friendly-page/

Comment: possible duplicate of [print from html pages in A4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/616200/print-from-html-pages-in-a4)

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Websites are created for screens, not printers.

You can add a [Print.css](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/media.html), to make the site print nicer, but you can't specify a paper size such as A4.

You can find more information about print stylesheets and how to use them [here](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Print_Stylesheets).

The best solution for printing, is to use PDFs, that's what they are for. Create a PDF that has the same data. You have full control over the print format in that case.

Reference : [Oded Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341485/how-to-make-a-html-page-in-a4-paper-size-pages)

Comment: In my search I found that this is possible using the @page{} attribute. Hope this could aid in your endeavor to get an accurate sizing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341485/how-to-make-a-html-page-in-a4-paper-size-pages

Answer (score 1):

if you want this level of control on printing, [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) can help. it supports regular pdf manipulation and templates. and the best of all, it's open source!